# Can the Facebook API be used to create link posts with summaries?

Tags: facebook, api, facebook-graph-api

When adding a link post in Facebook, a nice looking description (containing a snippet of text from the linked page) and thumbnail are automatically added to the post.

Is there a way to do this automatically using the Facebook API?  I am inclined to think that there is not, because posts added by [IFTTT](https://ifttt.com/), a popular web application that uses the Facebook API, [do not contain descriptions](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/q/25049/24105).  I am unclear as to whether this is a limitation with the Facebook API, and whether there is any way around it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, it's possible. You can use the Graph Api Method `/profile_id/feed`. The method receives the arguments message, picture, link, name, caption, description, source, place and tags. The facebook organize the parameters in a "nice looking summary and thumbnail".

You can get more information in the publishing section in the link http://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/api/

In c#:

```
        public static bool Share(string oauth_token, string message, string name, string link, string picture)
        {
            try
            {
                string url =
                    "https://graph.facebook.com/me/feed" +
                    "?access_token=" + oauth_token;

                StringBuilder post = new StringBuilder();
                post.AppendFormat("message={0}", HttpUtility.UrlEncode(message));
                post.AppendFormat("&name={0}", HttpUtility.UrlEncode(name));
                post.AppendFormat("&link={0}", HttpUtility.UrlEncode(link));
                post.AppendFormat("&picture={0}", HttpUtility.UrlEncode(picture));

                string result = Post(url, post.ToString());
            }
            catch (Exception)
            {
                return false;
            }

            return true;
        }

        private static string Post(string url, string post)
        {
            WebRequest webRequest = WebRequest.Create(url);
            webRequest.ContentType = "application/x-www-form-urlencoded";
            webRequest.Method = "POST";

            byte[] bytes = Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(post);

            webRequest.ContentLength = bytes.Length;

            Stream stream = webRequest.GetRequestStream();
            stream.Write(bytes, 0, bytes.Length);
            stream.Close();

            WebResponse webResponse = webRequest.GetResponse();

            StreamReader streamReader = new StreamReader(webResponse.GetResponseStream());

            return streamReader.ReadToEnd();
        }
```

**UPDATE:**

Open graph protocol meta tags: http://developers.facebook.com/docs/opengraphprotocol/

Comment: And Facebook automatically grabs the description - you don't have to get that yourself and pass it in the `description` argument?

Comment: Well, it's not well documented but sometimes when I send just a link Facebook does the work, sometimes not (I think it works only if the site have the open graph protocol meta tags implemented but I'm not sure about this). In order to have full control over the output you have to send everything. Because I'm doing it in my own website I have all the fields I need in variables, so it's not a problem for me to send everything.